# PHP echo results from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this PHP Code:

```
while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        //generate the list of emails address in an array
        $emails_list[] = $contacts2["email"];
    }
```

so it puts all my results into an array but when i echo `$emails_list` outside of the while loop it just displays `Array`

how can i make it display like:

`result1,result2,result3` etc

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: `echo implode(',',$emails_list);`

Comment: implode is definitely the way forward here.

Answer (score 1):

`$emails_list` is an array, so you have to loop through it to print its values:

```
foreach ($emails_list as $email) {
  print "email: $email";
}
```

Note that if you want to print an specific value, you can address with `$emails_list[index]`. So you can do `print $emails_list[0]`, for example.

If you then want to print values all together, do the following:

```
echo "(" . implode(',',$emails_list) . ")";
```

#### Test

```
$a=array(1,2,3);
echo "(" . implode(',',$a) . ")";
```

Returns

```
(1,2,3)
```

#### Update

Your code in http://pastebin.com/BwWZFrzZ shows that you are using:

```
echo 'Email sent to:' . $emails_list . '<br/ >';
```

So you can print

```
echo 'Email sent to: (' . implode(',',$emails_list) . ')<br/ >';
```

#### Update 2

Based on the github code it comes from (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), you need to add one email at a time:

```
//this is some clever **** to do with sending emails with attachments :D
$email = new PHPMailer();

while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
   $email->AddAddress($contacts2["email"]);
}

$email->From      = '...';
```

Comment: i am trying to run this code : http://pastebin.com/BwWZFrzZ : which sends emails using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: but i am getting an error saying: Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address. when i use $emails_list = implode(',',$emails_list); and echo $emails_list i get a list of all the email addresses separated by a comma

Comment: even if i use $email->AddAddress(implode(',',$emails_list)); i still get Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: You should check how `AddAddress` wants the list of emails to be given. Does it need an array or a list?

Comment: im not sure - it works fine if i use just a single email address though - like: $email->AddAddress("email@domain.com")

Comment: I see in the github link you have that it is used adding them one by one: `$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');`

Comment: Right okay... i was trying to achieve it sending emails with all the addresses in the header information of the email so each user can see its been sent to multiple addresses not just them

Comment: Yes, and it is possible. Check my Update2, as you can add emails while looping in your result.

Comment: i see - just done that and got: Fatal error: Call to a member function AddAddress() on a non-object in /home/integra/public_html/admin/billing/auto-send-invoice-by-email.php on line 49

Comment: I guess that's because you need to move the line `$email = new PHPMailer();` above the `while($contacts..)` line.

Comment: @user2710234 is your issue solved? Please keep updated and remember you can accept one answer so it is clear your issue is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
     //generate the list of emails address in an array
     $emails_list[] = $contacts2["email"];
}

$emails_list = implode(',', $emails_list);
echo "(". $emails_list . ")";
```

I think you should try like this,

```
$mail->AddAddress('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddAddress('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');
```

With `PHPMailer`, you can do as,

```
while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $mail->AddAddress($contacts2['emails'], $contacts2['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo implode(',', $emails_list);
```

here you will find the full details [php implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

```
 echo implode(",",$emails_list);
```

Comment: The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_push($emails_list,$contacts2["email"]);
```

then print the `$emails_list` outside of loop
may be solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
while($contacts2=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        //generate the list of emails address in an array
        array_push($emails_list,$contacts2["email"]);
    }
```

To show array data you can check with a print_r (just checking if it works)

```
print_r($emails_list)
```

and you can create a loop to take data one by one like below

```
for(int i=0;i<count($emails_list);$i++)
{
  echo $emails_list[$i]."<br>";
}
```